# Powering x until reach y in while loop

Tags: python

Hi I want to make an app that will be raise X to a power until it reaches Y.

I have for now something like this

```
x = 10 
y = 1000000
while x <= y: 
    x = x**x
print(x)
```

I don't want it in function.

I know that probably this is simple, but I just started learning Python :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but your question doesn't make much sense. It seems your code does what you want it to do, right? Also, the code isn't in a function, but a while loop...

Comment: Python cares about indentation. Since you want to print everytime you increase the counter, indent your print statement to the same level as the line above (`counter = counter ** counter`). By the way, are you meaning to raise counter the power of counter?

Comment: Voting to close until you ask a _specific_ question. As written, I'm not sure what problem you're asking us to solve - your code does what you say it does, and you have no function anywhere. What do you want us to do?

Comment: I will show you on example.

I have a=10 and b=10000000. I want powering "a" until it reach "b"(in this case 10000000)

Comment: @Monica By 'powering', do you mean `x^x` (raise to the power of itself) or `x^2` (squaring)? Because you're doing the former, not the latter - `**` is shorthad for 'raise to the power of'.

Comment: Of course I mean 'x^x'

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you are looking for. In python you want to use the operators for math as such += , -=, *=, /= for same variable operations.

```
counter = 10
while counter <= 1000000:
  counter *= counter
print(counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

10<sup>10<sup>10<sup>…</sup></sup></sup> (x) will never be equal to 10<sup>6</sup> (y) because 10<sup>10</sup> is four orders of magnitude larger. Your program will interpret x = 10 as less than 10<sup>6</sup>, execute x<sup>x</sup> (10<sup>10</sup>), interpret this value as greater than 10<sup>6</sup>, exit the loop, and print x (now 10<sup>10</sup>).

I don't think this is what you're trying to do; please consider the comments other users have left. I have a hunch you're looking for x<sup>n</sup>=y (10 * 10 * 10 …), for which you could simply use logarithms.